# Fixed columns on bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

Im using http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#extensions/fixed-columns.html to fix the first 4 columns.

On render table, first all rows are aligned well, but then, each row of the 4 fixed columns reduce the height 1px.

[image]

I tried with fix tr height, set the tr height after with jquery, change the order of the css files,...

Does anybody have an idea what it can be? Every hint is welcome!

Comment: A code snippet will enable more people to help you.. posting images is good but it doesn't tell what's wrong in the code..

Answer (score 0):

Post a JSFIDDLE so helpers can quickly diagnose the problem.